# php pdo code to search comma exploded input

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two textbox.

receipt no , coupon no

**User entering value in receipt textbox in comma exploded format.**

**and click search then get all value based on this inputed receipt in coupon textbox.**

my data in table like

receipt          coupon

501               - 1

501               - 2

501               - 3

502               - 4

502               - 5

502               - 6

**for ex -**

**Now if user enter 501,502 in receipttextbox and click search then it display all coupon of 501,502 in coupontextbox**

**I Need Output like below in coupon textbox after click search**

coupontextbox = 1,2,3,4,5,6

plz suggest how to get comma exploded input from receipt textbox and put on search query

below is my code

```
<?php
$coupons = "";
$db=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=circulation_scheme_prepaid','root','');
if($_POST && isset($_POST['submit']))
{                       
    $result=$db->prepare('SELECT coupon FROM scheme_master WHERE receipt_no=:receipt_no');
    $result->bindParam(':receipt_no',$_POST['receipt_no']);
    $result->execute(); 
    $data = $result->fetchAll();
    $coupons = array(); 
        
        foreach($data as $row)
        {               
            $coupons[] = $row['coupon'];            
        }

}
?>
```

coupon textbox

```
<input type="text" name="coupon" readonly="true" value="<?php echo implode(',', $coupons); ?>" class="field size2" />
```

Comment: sounds very easy to display the data from the `$coupons` array, no ?

Comment: but how to take input in by exploding comma from receipt textbox and put on search query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you  explode()  `$_POST['receipt_no']` to an array you can use it  with the IN operator. See [**PDO info**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)  on how to use IN with PDO.

The following code uses this.

```
if($_POST && isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
    $arr = explode(',', $_POST['receipt_no']);
    $in  = str_repeat('?,', count($arr) - 1) . '?';
    $sql = "SELECT coupon FROM scheme_master WHERE receipt_no IN ($in)";                     
    $result=$db->prepare($sql);
    $result->execute($arr); 
    $data = $result->fetchAll();
    $coupons = array(); 

        foreach($data as $row)
        {               
            $coupons[] = $row['coupon'];            
        }

}
```